# navigating an external frame within a frame wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, frame

I have a grid that is divided in three rows.  The top row has the menu options.  The middle row has another grid divided into two columns.  The left column has a frame (frameleft) and the right column has a frame (frameright).  As the user clicks on menu at top, the frameleft gets loaded with a page that shows the submenus for that option.

When they click on one of those submenus, I want to load a page on frameright but don't know how to do it.  In the mainwindow I can just call it by

```
frameright.Navigate(new DetailPage()).
```

But when I am with the frameleft page (MenuPage) I am not able to call it.

I don't know how to call the

```
frameright.navigate
```

method from within different frame or page. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventAggregator for this kinda purpose.

> The EventAggregator service is primarily a container for events that
>   allow decoupling of publishers and subscribers so they can evolve
>   independently. This decoupling is useful in modularized applications
>   because new modules can be added that respond to events defined by the
>   shell or, more likely, other modules.

Tons of example can be found by googling "Prism EventAggregator"

Comment: I googled the Prism EventAggregator but it seems too much for a simple command.  I just want to load a page into a frame.  I will keep searching though.  Not that I don't want to spend the time, but I am hoping for a simpler solution.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Look. Let's get the concept right. Look at what you want to do is a pure C# objects. And you have 3 different options to solve your problem. 1. Having sth like EventAggregator if you want your object completely decoupled. 2. Change your design so that your parent object (Menu) actually contains the object instance that you want to manipulate (Columns). 3. having some sort of "Locator" method from Menu to search through your controls and locate your column. You can do that by doing logical view search. These 3 are the more direct approach that I know of. Make sense ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I actually ended up doing it from within the frame itself.  I loaded my page into a frame that had sub frames in it and just handled it that way.  Thanks to all for your input.